# I want to check whether i have access or not of URL(Google Drive)

Tags: python

I want to check whether i have access or not of URL(Google Drive)  with my personal email id using python script, is it possible to check multiple url at once.
G Drive link which needs to be check Example "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1GvultE_db4nlDzxvva1Znl8Icwp9PhuG"

Comment: Why do you need to check multiple URLs to determine if you have access?

Comment: I think what OP meant was that he needs to check multiple URLs whether there is access for each URL.

Comment: You can issue request for each URL in  separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't have access to the URL it will redirect to `https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service....` so just check the URL

```
Urls = ['https://drive...', 'https://drive...']

import requests

for url in Urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if 'ServiceLogin' in response.url:
        print('no permission: ' + url)
    else:
        print('have permission: ' + url)
```

Comment: Thanks it's working .

Comment: you're welcome, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Done! Also can you help with " Python Script to Check whether documents are present in the google drive(URL) or not ?
" i am working on some large set of data and few url are present but documents are missing inside the url.also if possible i can get the owner email id/Name who actually worked on the URL.

Comment: you can create new question with code you have tried, and its not possible to get owner email for url/file

Comment: Sure creating new Question